# How to boot to a Ubuntu 12.04 installation which is not listed in grub2 anymore?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I have a computer with 3 hard drives on it. I have Ubuntu 12.04 on my newest and biggest hard drive and Windows XP on my 2nd hard drive and a old version of Ubuntu 7.04 on the third hard drive.

Everything was working perfectly and I was using Grub to choose between the different systems. I was using Windows XP and it automatically did some upgrades and the next time I tried to use Windows XP, it would not not boot up. So I tried using the Windows XP CD to repair it and I used a dos command like a `dltmbr` or something similar to it and when I tried to boot into Ubuntu 12.04 it would not boot!

I tried the the boot-repair to fix it but it said that Ubuntu 12.04 is not there and only Windows XP and Ubuntu 7.04 were the only selections. So I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 hoping it would find it and fix grub and it could not find it either.

I installed a new version of Ubuntu 12.04 over Ubuntu 7.04 on the 3rd hard drive by mistake. It  does not cause a problem and I can see my files in Windows XP and  Ubuntu 12.04 on the first hard drive. When I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on the first hard drive I created a separate home partition so all of my files are safe.

I want to know how I can update grub or change something in Ubuntu 12.04 on my first hard drive so it will boot up. I believe the  kernel is missing and that is why grub can't find it. I need to access Ubuntu 12.04 on my first hard drive because Firefox has all of my bookmarks and cookies and I don't want to start over again. Any help on this would be great!

Comment: Try booting up to First or Last Drive containing Ubuntu by the same way you select the liveCd or Live USB Drive  Boot devices from Boot menu for installation, it will boot you into Ubuntu . After that just run `sudo update-grub` .

Comment: "because Firefox has all of my bookmarks and cookies" these will be in the /home partition you created and should be available from the 'new' 12.04's file manager

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling grub from a livecd? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstall_from_the_LiveCD

Comment: yes, I tried that when I install the new version of ubuntu 12.04 on the 3rd hard drive but it did not find ubuntu 12.04 on my first hard drive. The kernal and boot info must missing.

Comment: Please indicate your [Boot-Info URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can update GRUB. Boot a LiveCD, and then follow this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#ChRoot to chroot into your install of Ubuntu, and then run 'update-grub'.

Comment: How update-grub will help, if he lost his kernel and also the boot information

Comment: Also, you are giving instruction for Gento linux to an Ubuntu user. They are significantly different, especially in boot/grub issue

Comment: The Gentoo instructions for chrooting are fine. And if he lost his kernel, then he can install it with `sudo apt-get install linux-image-[version] linux-headers-[version]`.

Comment: Yes, Very fine. We can happily mount a partition with `/dev/hda3`in Ubuntu !!!

Comment: Ok, substitute 'hd' with 'sd'

Comment: I edited the answer with link to ubuntu grub chroot

Comment: Great. The edit was rejected, but I myself then did the edit again.

Comment: Thanks for all of the advice. I did change to my 1st hard drive which has Ubuntu 12.04 installed on it (which I cannot access) in bios. Grub came up and I choose ubuntu 12.04 and an error message displayed. It said "Gave up waiting for root device.

Comment: I could not enter in all of my comments above. Here is the rest of it. Common Problems. Boot avgs(cat/proc/cmdline). check root delay = check root. missing modules cat/proc/modules; ls/dev Alert! /dev/disk/by-uuid/6ba53d-4dll-4398-af59-7669dc858042 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!"

Comment: Here is the end of my comment. The shell is Busybox v1 18.5. I tried the "sudo apt-get install linux-image [version] linux-headers [version] command but it said "sudo is not recognized". So it looks like I don't have a kernal and boot information. Where do I run this sudo apt-get command if Busybox does not have sudo in it? I really appreciate everybody's help!

Comment: Try and chroot as explained above.

Comment: I am a beginner and I need some help with chroot. My system files are in dev/sdc1. My swap is dev/sdc2. My home partition is dev/sdc3. I booted up the live ubuntu cd. I went to a command line. I guess, I need to mount dev/sc1 where my systems files are at. I tried sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt and I got a message "you must specify the filesystem type." I am not sure what this means. What should I do to mount dev/sdc1? Thanks

Comment: I just used gparted on the live cd and noticed that there was a boot flag on dev/sdc3 which is my /home partition. Is this where grub is at? Does this flag mean anything? thanks

Comment: `sudo mount -o ext4 /dev/sdc1 /mnt` - if your partition is ext4, otherwise replace ext4 with ext3, ext2 or ext1 :)

Comment: sudo mount -o ext4 /dev/sdc1 /mnt
mount: /dev/sdc1: more filesystems detected. This should not happen,
       use -t <type> to explicitly specify the filesystem type or
       use wipefs(8) to clean up the device.

mount: you must specify the filesystem type

Comment: I was able to do everything. I chroot and updated grub. It did not find Ubuntu on sdc1. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: root@ubuntu:/# grub-install --recheck /dev/sdc
Installation finished. No error reported.
root@ubuntu:/# update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found Microsoft Windows XP Home Edition on /dev/sda1
Found Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (12.04) on /dev/sdb1
done
root@ubuntu:/# 
It did not find Ubuntu 12.04 on /dev/sdc1 boo! What can I do? thanks

Comment: I was able to do it. I added -t ext4 and did the chroot and then updated grub and everyting worked! I use your suggestion -t ext4 for the mount command. It worked! I was able to boot into ubuntu 12.04 on sdc1. Thank you for your help!